# Construct a subsequence that converge to a cluster point

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

Suppose $\ell$ is a cluster point of sequence$\{x_k\}$. For $\varepsilon >0$, we know for each integer $N>0$ there exists $k>N,$ $|x_k-\ell |<\varepsilon$. So we can pick $N_1=1$ and set first term of the subsequence $x_{k_1}$ where $k_1>1\implies |x_{k_1}-\ell |<\varepsilon$, we can pick the a second term by picking $N_2=k_1+1$, then again we can find some $k_2>N_2 \implies |x_{k_2}-\ell |<\varepsilon$, clearly we can continue this process infinitely many times, and hence $\{x_{k_n}\}$ is a subsequence of $\{x_k\}$ that converges to $\ell$.

Comment: Is there a question?  Your description is OK.

Comment: I wanted to verify if my proof can be used as legit proof since it's different from the solution I'm looking at. Thanks.

Comment: Is the $\varepsilon$ fixed? If it is fixed then your argument does not work. Take $\varepsilon_n=1/n$, and for these $\varepsilon_n$ find the required subsequence.

Comment: @uerse611582 I believe $\epsilon$ is arbitrary but I'm a bit confused can you elaborate a bit more? Thanks

Comment: You need $\epsilon \to 0$, otherwise you get a cluster (?) of points around $l$ without convergence.

Comment: So for a fixed $\epsilon$, the subsequence you created does not necessarily converge to $l$. It is just in the $\epsilon$ neighbourhood of $l$. To fix this issue. You just need a little change in your argument. And that is: for each step instead of finding $x_{k_i}$ for $\epsilon$, you just need to find $x_{k_i}$ for $\epsilon_i=\frac{1}{i}$,$i=1, 2, 3, ...$.